# Overloading, with r-value refs, constructor of class template

Tags: c++, c++11

While initially it seems to be [working](http://ideone.com/wO4akf), when called through a maker function (to have template argument deduction), the existence of two overloads, one with `T const&` and one with `T&&` [breaks compilation](http://ideone.com/VRpUQX) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// -----------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename F>
struct Test
{
    T m_resource;
    F m_deleter; 

    Test(T&& resource, F&& deleter) 
    : m_resource(move(resource)), m_deleter(move(deleter))
    {
    }
    Test(T const& resource, F const& deleter) 
    : m_resource(resource), m_deleter(deleter)
    {
    }
};
// -----------------------------------------------

// -----------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename F>
Test<T, F> test(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return Test<T, F>(move(t), move(f));
}
template<typename T, typename F>
Test<T, F> test(T const& t, F const& f)
{
    return Test<T, F>(t, f);
}
// -----------------------------------------------

int main() 
{
    // construct from temporaries --------------------
    Test<int*, function<void(int*)>> t(new int, [](int *k) {}); // OK - constructor
    auto tm = test(new int, [](int *k){});                      // OK - maker function
    // -----------------------------------------------

    // construct from l-values -----------------------
    int *N = new int(24);
    auto F = function<void(int*)>([](int *k){});

    Test<int*, function<void(int*)>> tt(N, F); // OK    - construction
    auto m = test(N, F);                       // Error - maker function
    // -----------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: @dyp I'm practically copy-pasting the implementation of `scoped_resource` from [here](http://www.andrewlsandoval.com/scope_exit/scoped_resource.h) There are some shady parts I try to sort out. 
A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename F>
Test<T, F> test(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return Test<T, F>(move(t), move(f));
}
```

This function template has two parameters that are *universal references*. Parameters of function template of the form *template-type-parameter* `&&` obey special deduction rules: If the argument is an lvalue, the template type parameter is deduced to be an lvalue reference type. If the argument is an rvalue, the deduced type is not a reference.

```
auto m = test(N, F);
```

`int* N` and `function<void(int*)> F` are lvalues, hence for the function template above, `T` is deduced to `int*&` and `F` is deduced to `function<void(int*)>&`. Reference collapsing applies, and the parameter `T&&` becomes `int*& &&` and is collapsed to `int*&` (similarly for `F&&`).

Therefore, your class template is instantiated with a reference type (`T == int*&`, `F == function<void(int*)>&`). Inside the class template,

```
Test(T&& resource, F&& deleter)
Test(T const& resource, F const& deleter)
```

will produce the same signature, since `int*& &&` and `int*& const&` are both collapsed to `int*&`, similarly for `F`.

---

Note that a function with a parameter `int*&` is preferred over a function with a parameter `int* const&` when the argument is not const. Hence, the function template

```
template<typename T, typename F>
Test<T, F> test(T const& t, F const& f)
```

will not be used in the line where the error appears. In general, universal reference parameters are *very* greedy.

The typical solution is to use *perfect forwarding* as described in [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755922).

Comment: `...will produce the same signature, since int*& && and int*& const& are both collapsed to int*&` Reference collapsing swallows cv qualifiers ?!

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou `const` applied to a reference type has not effect: `int& const == int&`. Similarly, `struct foo { int& x; void bar() const { x = 42; } };` is allowed. `int const& const&` is collapsed to `int const&`.

Answer (score 6):

```
template<typename T, typename F>
Test<T, F> test(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return Test<T, F>(move(t), move(f));
}
```

This function handles lvalues and rvalues. When you call `test(N, F)` the arguments are non-const lvalues, so the overload above is used, **not** the `test(const T&, const F&)` one. That instantiates your class template as `Test<int*&, std::function<void(int*)>&>` which is not what you want.

You only need one maker function:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto test(T&& t, F&& f)
-> Test<typename std::decay<T>::type, typename std::decay<F>::type>
{
    return { std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f) };
}
```

This will accept any combination of lvalues and rvalues, it will ensure you return the desired type, and it will perfectly forward the arguments to the `Test` constructor using their original value category.

You should read/watch [Universal References in C++11](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: If that's the case (universal refs can handle the totality of cases) why `push_back` has overloads both for `T const&` and `T&&` ? To repeat myself I'm only mentioning code that I found in a standard [proposal](http://www.andrewlsandoval.com/scope_exit/scoped_resource.h)

Comment: Maybe the  presense of the two constructors lifts the burden from the interface function of explicitly dealing with constness / l-r valuness of the arguments ?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou A `vector` may not be instantiated for references as value types, and `push_back` is not a function template (the overloads are `push_back(value_type&&)` and `push_back(value_type const&)`. For `vector<vector<double>>`, a `push_back(vector<double>&&)` allows calling `push_back( {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} )`

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou, I don't see any "make" function in that proposal that overloads `T&&` and `const T&` where `T` is a template parameter. If you copy code and change it, and it doesn't work, maybe the problem is in your changes. You need to understand the difference between a deduced `T` (where `T&&` can be a "universal reference") and a non-deduced `T` like your constructors or `vector::push_back`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, I misread the `make_scoped_resource_unchecked` method (and `make_scoped_resource` below), don't know how I ended up typing the two different versions  when all is just passed by value. Thnx for the remarks and the info on deducable contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the auto type guessing fails as this lines says `prog.cpp:18:2: error: ‘Test<T, F>::Test(const T&, const F&) [with T = int*&; F = std::function<void(int*)>&]’ cannot be overloaded` Your compiler tries to instantiate it with a int*& and not a int*. I'm pretty sure if you specify the type explicitly (which is I understand what you want to avoid) it will work fine.

And I don't really understand why you put this in your maker function

```
Test<T, F> test(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return Test<T, F>(move(t), move(f));
}
```

`t` and `f` are already rvalue references so you don't need to call move on them

Comment: *"`t` and `f` are already rvalue references so you don't need to call move on them"* `t` and `f` are variables (names of variables), therefore, as expressions, they are lvalue-expressions. Otherwise, you could accidentally move twice from them. Every expression that is the name of something (but enumerators) is an lvalue-expression.

Comment: I guess I learned something then. I never had to use them in that way since I mostly call the move constructors from the STL and didn't feel the need to make my own for now.